# Why is the const lost in an expression like `const T&` where T is an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

I'm working on a templated class, and given an incoming type `T` the template needs to map to a "safe" const reference. (This is essentially to avoid handing the ability to mutate to a wrapped function when it's called; see [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/a1cc8c551/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h#L1298-L1300) for the real code).

The original author wrote something equivalent to this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using SafeReference =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_scalar_v<T>, T, const T&>;
```

The scalar part isn't interesting here, but what's interesting is `const T&`. This looks right to me, but it's not:

```cpp
struct Foo{};
using Bar = Foo&&;

// A failing static assert, and a reduced version. It turns out `const Bar&`
// is `Foo&`.
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const Foo&, SafeReference<Bar>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const Foo&, const Bar&>);
```

I understand that `Foo&&` becomes `Foo&` due to the rules for [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). I also understand that the `const` is probably "lost" because it tries to make a reference const rather than making the referred-to type const. But I don't even know what to Google in order to confirm that.

**Which part of the standard says that the `const` is "lost" in an expression like `const T&` for a templated `T` expanding to an rvalue reference?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which part of the standard says that the const is "lost" in an expression like const T& for a templated T expanding to an rvalue reference?

From [dcl.ref/p6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6):

> If a *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param]) or a *decltype-specifier* ([dcl.type.decltype]) denotes a type TR that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to create the type *lvalue reference to cv `TR`* **creates the type *lvalue reference to `T`***, while an attempt to create the type *rvalue reference to cv TR* creates the type `TR`.

The quote probably explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: This is also called reference collapsing as far as I know.

Comment: @Mechap Yes, it is mentioned as a note below [point 6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6).